# I need to throw a pop up box based on a selection from a dropdown box that meet a range of criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to throw a pop up box when a selection is made on a drop down box, and the selection meets a range of criteria. (The dropdown box is created from a coldfusion output query). I am new to Javascript so I don't know what I am doing wrong. My code is as follows...

```
function secondoccupantcheck(obj){

    qtenantid = new Array(#ValueList(qRecurring.iTenant_ID)#);
    qoccupancy = new Array(#ValueList(qRecurring.ioccupancyposition)#);
    qdescription = new Array(#ValueList(qRecurring.cdescription)#);

    for (i=0;i<=(qRecurring.length-1);i++){
        if ((obj.value ==qtenantid[i]) && (qoccupancy[i] == 1) && (qdescription[i].indexOf("Second Resident")>=0))  
        {
            alert('Resident will be second occupant and occupancy will be zero');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If an occupant in an assisted living house (iTenant_id) wants to move to another room and is currently the main tenant in his or room (iOccupancyposition =1). If he or she will be the second tenant in the room he or she wants to move to, I need to throw an alert box with a message. I can't seem to get it to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few quick things:

1. I am assuming you have your JS code surrounded by a CFOUTPUT to
   get actual values on client side.
2. Another assumption include number of values will be same in all
   three fields viz.  `iTenant_ID`, `ioccupancyposition` and
   `cdescription`. If this is not the case or there are consecutive blank values then this logic will not work!
3. For `qdescription` you need to use [quotedValueList()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/quotedvaluelist.html) function
           instead of [valueList()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/valuelist.html) otherwise browser will throw a JS error.
4. For the `for` loop the length should come from `qtenantid.length`
           instead of `qRecurring.length` OR you need to change your code to: `for (i=0;i<=(#qRecurring.recordCount#-1);i++){`
5. Your JavaScrip function is using parameter as an obj and use only
   one value out of this object. Why you are passing an object? Pass only the selected value and call is something like `val` and use it in if condition like: `if ((val ==qtenantid[i]) && (qoccupancy[i] == 1) && (qdescription[i].indexOf("Second Resident")>=0))`

There are more things that you can check for error handling. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will try your suggestions!!